# Starting mongodb with plain backup of previous /data/db contents

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, backup, restore

I'be grabbed all files from /data/db dir from other sever and now trying to start mongo with it on another one. Here are the files I have:

```
-rw-------  1 root    root    1073741824 Feb  2 11:21 j._0
drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb nogroup       4096 May  3 12:02 journal
-rw-------  1 root    root      67108864 Feb 12 06:43 metadocs-node_db.0
-rw-------  1 root    root     134217728 Jun 27  2012 metadocs-node_db.1
-rw-------  1 root    root      16777216 Feb 12 06:43 metadocs-node_db.ns
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mongodb nogroup          0 May  3 12:02 mongod.lock
-rw-------  1 root    root    1073741824 Aug 28  2012 prealloc.1
-rw-------  1 root    root    1073741824 Aug 28  2012 prealloc.2
root@mtg:/var/lib/mongodb#
```

While starting, I get (from logfile /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log):

```
Fri May  3 12:02:01 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: 
"/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb",$
Fri May  3 12:02:01 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Fri May  3 12:02:01 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Fri May  3 12:02:01 [initandlisten] couldn't open /var/lib/mongodb/_metadocs-node_db.ns errno:13 Permission denied
Fri May  3 12:02:01 [initandlisten] error couldn't open file /var/lib/mongodb/_metadocs-node_db.ns terminating
Fri May  3 12:02:01 dbexit:
```

I'm running

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

So, what I'm doing wrong? What files are missing for mongodb to start? Why I'm getting "Permission denied"? Working as root, BTW. No other instances of mongo is running. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure service start script doesn't run mongodb as a different user? You could either look at the script to confirm or chmod 777 all of the files under your db dir and try running.

Comment: @JamesWahlin you was right. Chown'ed files and mongodb started. Please, answer the question and I'll mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting MongoDB as a service, the packaged start script will start your mongod server under a MongoDB user. Looking at a MongoDB 2.4 init.d script for mongod shows the user as "mongod". When setting up data and log directories it is important that the MongoDB user has read/write access to the directories and files contained within.